# Integrating Laravel 8 with Pimcore

Tags: php, laravel, integration, pimcore, pim

There are 10 e-commerce shops (1.5k products per each).
Every shop is developed in Laravel 8 and has its own MySQL DB. Each DB is quite different.

Is it a good idea to store all products in Pimcore (particular products connected with parent shop object) and sync them with each e-commerce?
If so, does Pimcore has default API enabling syncing products with POSes (which does not require developers ingerention on PIMs side)?

Our aim is to store all products in 1 relational DB (currently they are in .xls file :)).
We are able to provide frontend and e-commerce logic on Laravels side.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an architectural question (not one, many) and it is far beyond the scope of SO. There is no definite answer to that. Basically I would say: Why using Laravel if Pimcore is based on the awesome Symfony Framework? You can have all this functionality easily within one system, this is what Pimcore is intended for. Or you might have a look at the Pimcore DataHub and provide an API. Ask a senior requirements engineer or software architect.

Comment: This question is to broad and doesn't ask for any specific technical problems. Define one data source for your products (pimcore) and get the products via an api in pimcore to all your shops. If there are technical detail questions or problems fell free to ask again